# jQuery return text from span tags based on label tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML rendered on my page:

```
<div class='panel'>
    <div>
        <div class='section'>
            <ul class='properties'>
                <li>
                    <label>Claim.Claimant</label>
                    <span class="value">Smith, John</span>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <label>Claim.LossDate</label>
                    <span class="value">04/22/2014</span>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <label>Claim.LossDescription</label>
                    <span class="value">I was injured.</span>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to retrieve the text that is populated in the span tag using jQuery.

I've tried with zero success:

```
alert($("<label>Claim.Claimant</label>").find("span.value"));
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you want the text in all `span` tags, or a specific one?

Comment: I need to search for a specific one based on the label

Comment: @SidM I see different text in each label. What do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your syntax for the selector is incorrect. You want to follow basic CSS rules, not encoded HTML in the selector. Then you can use `filter()` to find an element by it's text. Try this:

```
var valueText = $('label').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == 'Claim.Claimant';
}).next('span.value').text();
alert(valueText); // = 'Smith, John'
```

Note that `filter()` is a lot faster than the `:contains` selector.

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5XWz7/)

Answer (score 5):

You should do:

```
var $yourspan = $('label:contains(Claim.Claimant)').parent().find('span')
```

Basically it

- finds a label containing a specific text
- finds its parent
- in this parent element searches for a span

See the **[live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/albertmatyi/JK8R7/)**

Check out the documentation for [`contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

Edit:

According to [this jsperf test](http://jsperf.com/jquery-contains-vs-filter) [Rory's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24514386/209427) is indeed more performant.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the text value of a span tag using .text()

This will get the text from all the span tags with class "value":

```
$("span.value").text()
```

If you want a specific span tag either assign unique IDs to each of them, or refer to them with an index:

```
$($("span.value")[0]).text()
```

Comment: you are not fetching text of spam based on label.